# Get URL parameter inside prepare() function, instead of get() / post()

Tags: python, tornado

I am using tornado and I declared a RequestHandler with a single parameter like this:

```
class StuffHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, stuff_name):
        ...

app = Application([
    (r'/stuff/(.*)/public', StuffHandler)
])
```

Now I added another handler for `'/stuff/(.*)/private'`, which requires the user to be authenticated:

```
class PrivateStuffHandler(RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self, stuff_name):
        ...
```

This of course will cause `get_current_user()` to be called before `get()`. The problem is that, in order for `get_current_user()` to run, I need to know the `stuff_name` parameter.

So I thought that I may use the `prepare()` or the `initialize()` method, which is called before `get_current_user()`. However, I can't seem to access `stuff_name` from those methods. I tried putting `stuff_name` as a parameter but it didn't work, then I tried calling `self.get_argument("stuff_name")` but it didn't work either.

How do I access an URL parameter from the `prepare()` method?

Comment: you could store it in class variable and retrieve it? like self.stuff_name = stuff_name?

Comment: @lamirap but then how do I detect when a person visits `/stuff/a/private` or `/stuff/b/private`? The self.stuff_name will always be the same... (Or: where do I update it when it changes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I asked [straight to Tornado developers](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1673) and a helpful user made me notice that there's [`self.path_args`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.path_args) and [`self.path_kwargs`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.path_kwargs) available from anywhere in the class.

So, from the `prepare()` method (or even the `get_current_user()` method), I can do:

```
stuff_name = self.path_args[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `self.request.path` to get the full path, then achieve the value in path which you need.

Comment: it can be used in `prepare()`.

Comment: Maybe this is the only solution... But it's very ugly :(

Comment: Also: what if I change the path definition from `'/stuff/(.*)/private'` to `'/private-stuff/(.*)'`? Would I need to change the logic inside `prepare()`?

Comment: @wil93 I think so. it's really ugly ~

Comment: maybe you can get the URL pattern in Application. Then get the value by using URL pattern and `self.request.path`.